# modal window does not hide in ajaxStop function in jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, bootstrap-modal

`ajaxStart function` is working correctly.But modal window does not hide in `ajaxStop function` in `jquery`.

This is my code

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
   $('#loading-modal').modal('hide');
});
```

There is a `error` in `console`.
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`

Comment: can you please put `alert(1);` just before hide code and confirm whether `ajaxStop` is getting executed or not. Also please share HTML too.

Comment: yes it is executed.

Comment: check your js files overwrited or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `jquery` file or `bootstrap.js` file `overwriting again`.
sometimes it's the issue.
cheers.